# How to prove simplification of logic(A and B implies A) in Coq

Tags: coq

I want to prove

```
Lemma simplification (A B: Prop) : A /\ B -> A.
```

How do I bring A /\ B?
Then how do I bring A from A /\ B?

Answer (score 1):

First answer: the theorem you want to prove already exists, it is called `proj1`.

You can verify what I say by typing the following command.

```
Check proj1.
```

You can use this theorem by simply typing.

```
apply proj1.
Qed.
```

There is a similar theorem named `proj2` for the other side of the and-statement.  You can find these theorems by just typing:

```
Search hyp:(_ /\ _).
```

Second answer: after you have typed the line you give as example, you enter what is called *proof mode*.  The system prints the text that you need to prove to you, and send proof commands that are usually called *tactics*.  The basic tactics are described in a few tutorials.  For instance, I can suggest [a tutorial that I wrote](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00001173/en/).  Many of the simple tactics only apply simple rules of *natural deduction*.  For instance, when you want to reason about and-statements, there are two things you might want to do.

- Either you want to prove an and-statement
- Or you want to use an and-statement

In the current situation, you have two logical connectives: you want to prove an implication and this implication has an and-statement as the left-hand side, so you will later want to use an and-statement.

To prove an implication, the trick is to assume the left-hand side.  This is done with the following tactic:

```
intros factAB.
```

After that, the system displays the following goal.

```
 1 subgoal

  A, B : Prop
  factAB : A /\ B
  ============================
  A
```

The subgoal has two parts, the top part contains the objects that are assume to exist and the logical facts that are assumed to hold.  In this case, `A /\ B` is assumed to hold and this fact is named `factAB` (we chose that name).

Now to use the factAB, you can type:

```
destruct factAB as [factA factB].
```

Between the brackets, we provide two names, because we know that an and-statement contains two more elementary facts.

After you ran the destruct command, you have an hypothesis named `factA` which says that `A` holds, and you have to prove `A`.  You can finish the proof by just saying that `factA` is the proof, by typing `exact factA`, or by saying that the proof is among the assumptions, by typing `assumption`.